# I can't get the characteristics of a Restriction in JENA

Tags: java, owl, jena

I have an Owl model which I defined in Protégé with the following restriction:

```
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/herve/ontologies/2020/animals#isFriendOf">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/herve/ontologies/2020/animals#Dog"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/herve/ontologies/2020/animals#Man"/>
    <rdfs:range>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/herve/ontologies/2020/animals#isFriendOf"/>
            <owl:maxQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:maxQualifiedCardinality>
            <owl:onClass rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/herve/ontologies/2020/animals#Man"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I try to get the characteristics of this restriction in JENA. I get the "isFriendOf" ObjectProperty and list the range:

```
ExtendedIterator ranges = objProperty.listRange();
while (ranges.hasNext()) {
    OntResource resource = (OntResource) ranges.next();
    if (resource instanceof OntClass) {
        OntClass onClass = (OntClass) resource;
        if (onClass.isRestriction()) {
           Restriction restriction = onClass.asRestriction();
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

But the restriction is not a MaxCardinalityRestriction. The evaluation of this condition returns false:

```
if (restriction.isMaxCardinalityRestriction()) {
   MaxCardinalityRestriction restriction = restriction.asMaxCardinalityRestriction();
}
```

I understand why it is not working, because this a a MaxQualifiedCardinalityRestriction (MaxCardinalityQRestriction ?) and not a MaxCardinalityRestriction. However there is no API in the Restriction class to get this particular restriction type.

How must I use the API in my case?

Comment: Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684076/support-of-owlmaxqualifiedcardinality-and-owlminqualifiedcardinality-restricti

Comment: Jena OWL never made it to full OWL 2 support, thus, qualified cardinality restrictions aren't built-in. That means, either you do it on the RDF triple level - which is a bit verbose - or as suggested you use [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api/wiki) which provides a bridge between Apache Jena and OWL API that in fact provides full and proper OWL 2 support and works on the level of OWL entities (class expressions, axioms, etc.) compared to triples like in Jena.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look at the ONT_API first:! It seems exactly what I need.